# Getting image url to post to MySQL after upload

Tags: php, mysql

So this syntax does connect and get the information posted to the database, but I can not figure out how to get the url of the image to post to the database. Whatever I change test1 to it doesn't post.

```
protected function trim_file_name($name, $type, $index) {
    // Remove path information and dots around the filename, to prevent uploading
    // into different directories or replacing hidden system files.
    // Also remove control characters and spaces (\x00..\x20) around the filename:
    $file_name = trim(basename(stripslashes($name)), ".\x00..\x20");
    // Add missing file extension for known image types:
    if (strpos($file_name, '.') === false &&
        preg_match('/^image\/(gif|jpe?g|png)/', $type, $matches)) {
        $file_name .= '.'.$matches[1];
    }
    if ($this->options['discard_aborted_uploads']) {
        while(is_file($this->options['upload_dir'].$file_name)) {
            $file_name = $this->upcount_name($file_name);
        }
    }
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","-----","-----");
    if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("-----", $con);

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (postid, post_content)
    VALUES ('', 'test1')");

    mysql_close($con);
    {
    header("Location: http://snarb.com/index.php");
    }
    return $file_name;

}
```

Comment: I have changed it to the following --- mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (postid, post_content) VALUES ('NULL', '" . $upload_url . "')"); --- This just dumps in an empty line. I need it to give me the path to the image in http:// format.

Comment: if the id is AUTO_INCREMENT let postid away.mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (post_content)
    VALUES ('test1')");

Comment: Sure I can take that out, but my question is how do I get it to post the url.

Comment: @IsaacBoda Where does your `$upload_url` come from?

Answer (score 0):

Change your mysql_query line to:

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (post_content) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($file_name) . "')");
```